# Zend MVC, views/actions scheduling

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I'm using Zend MVC and I'm looking for a way to schedule the views and actions but I don't know where to begin. The idea is to get a file like an XML file where I can define all the views of the website, to define the possible actions from a view and defines the transition.

Do you know where I can find some info (tuto) on this topic ?

Regards,
Ced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is schedule the right word or did you mean something like **define the views and actions**, as in an application/website skeleton?

If that's the case you want the project profile '.zfproject.xml'. This file is automatically updated when you use the Zend Framework CLI tool. Read about it:

1. [Using the CLI Tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html);
2. [Using Zend_Tool On The Command Line](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.usage.cli.html).